# JAXB jar files incompatible with java 1.6.0?

Tags: jaxb

I'm new to JAXB and I want to marshal and un-marshal XML/Objects to Objects/XML.

I have **downloaded JWSDP 2.0** from (worth 22.69 MB) Sun's site.

I have set Environment variables as

```
JAVA_HOME :-   D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0  
JWSDP_HOME :-   D:\Sun\jwsdp-2.0  
JAXB_HOME :- D:\Sun\jwsdp-2.0\jaxb  
PATH :- D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0\bin;D:\Sun\jwsdp-2.0\jwsdp-shared\bin;
```

I'm trying to compile a simple XSD file (named tp.xsd) using XJC (which is present in `D:\Sun\jwsdp-2.0\jaxb\bin`).

I'm getting the following output when I try to compile it:

**D:\Sun\jwsdp-2.0\jaxb\bin>xjc tp.xsd**

```
parsing a schema...  
compiling a schema...  
generated\Bookdata.java  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Class.getSimpl
eName()Ljava/lang/String;  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel$JReferencedClass.name(JCodeModel.java:54
5)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JFormatter.t(JFormatter.java:283)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JClass.generate(JClass.java:358)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JFormatter.g(JFormatter.java:346)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JAnnotationUse.generate(JAnnotationUse.java:388)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JFormatter.g(JFormatter.java:346)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass.declare(JDefinedClass.java:767)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JFormatter.d(JFormatter.java:372)   
        at com.sun.codemodel.JFormatter.write(JFormatter.java:402)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JPackage.build(JPackage.java:434)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel.build(JCodeModel.java:297)  
        at com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel.build(JCodeModel.java:287)  
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:378)  
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:196)  
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver._main(Driver.java:121)  
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.access$000(Driver.java:79)  
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$1.run(Driver.java:101)
```

Can you help me finding the solution? I know that the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Class.getSimpl eName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

occurs due to compiler and class file incompatibility, but I'm not getting what to do!

When I run java -version command it shows:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\welcome>java -version  
java version "1.6.0_23"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)  
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: In the subject of your post you are referring to Java 1.6 but in your post it is clearly that you are using JDK 1.5. You should switch to the latest JDK 1.6 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jaxb libraries are included in java 1.6. You'll get all kinds of crazy classloader errors if you add the jar too.

In this case, it looks like it xjc picked the wrong version of the jar.

### edit

xjc should be bundled in the JDK, in your post you are using the xjc that comes in the jabx stand-alone pack. Go to the folder where you installed java 1.6, check that you have the xjc.exe or xjc.bat there and run it from that folder.
And like Robert mentioned above, be sure that you're using Java 1.6

Comment: Thnx for the reply...But i dont get which is solution part??
What shud i do to make the xsd file successfully compile???

Comment: Tons of thnx to u frnd...It worked..i downloaded java 6 complete new pack and installed...It contains xjc and tried running it...
(But my system was updating java regularly so why didnt it download latest things which are in java 1.6 but not in java 1.5??? why my system was saying i'm running java 1.6 as shown in my question??)

Answer (score 0):

This is a supplemental answer to the original post.  The question on the comments section was:

**(But my system was updating java regularly so why didnt it download latest things which are in java 1.6 but not in java 1.5??? why my system was saying i'm running java 1.6 as shown in my question??)**

When you type "java -version" on the command prompt, Windows resolves it using the PATH environment variable.  There are multiple locations where one can find the **java.exe** file.  The obvious one is the location of the downloaded JRE (i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java[SOME JRE]).  Another, no so obvious, location is Windows' System32 folder.  I also just found out that my Windows 8 machine has a java.exe shortcut under C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath. The point is that could be many paths where the java.exe (or shortcut) can reside. The one encountered first in the PATH wins out.

If you want a specific version of java to be used to execute programs outside your development environment, you must place that location as the first entry in the PATH (to make sure it finds that location first).